# How to add class to image anchors only with jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, anchor

In a div with class `tiny-content`, i have some image anchors and text anchors. Is it possible with jquery to add a class, lets say `lb-anchor` (lightbox anchor) to only the image anchors?

This is the situation now:

```
<div class="tiny-content">
    <a href="images/1.jpg"><img src="images/1.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="images/2.jpg"><img src="images/2.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="images/3.jpg"><img src="images/3.jpg" /></a>
                        
    <a href="example.com">Normal link</a>
    <a href="example.com">Normal link</a>
</div>
```

And it should be:

```
<div class="tiny-content">
    <a class="lb-anchor" href="images/1.jpg"><img src="images/1.jpg" /></a>
    <a class="lb-anchor" href="images/2.jpg"><img src="images/2.jpg" /></a>
    <a class="lb-anchor" href="images/3.jpg"><img src="images/3.jpg" /></a>
                        
    <a href="example.com">Normal link</a>
    <a href="example.com">Normal link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Sure it is, you just need a way to determine which of the anchors should get such a class. You could maybe check if the `href` value contains an image extension. Or check if the child of an anchor is a child. Make an effort and let us know if you get stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(".tiny-content a:has(img)").addClass( "lb-anchor" );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tiny-content">
    <a href="images/1.jpg"><img src="images/1.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="images/2.jpg"><img src="images/2.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="images/3.jpg"><img src="images/3.jpg" /></a>
                        
    <a href="example.com">Normal link</a>
    <a href="example.com">Normal link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use this query and `.addClass()`

```js
$('div.tiny-content > a[href^=images]').addClass('lb-anchor')
```

```css
.lb-anchor {
  margin: 10px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tiny-content">
  <a href="images/1.jpg"><img src="images/1.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="images/2.jpg"><img src="images/2.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="images/3.jpg"><img src="images/3.jpg" /></a>

  <a href="example.com">Normal link</a>
  <a href="example.com">Normal link</a>
</div>
```

---

#### Reference

[Child Selector (“parent > child”)](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

[Attribute Starts With Selector [name^=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Comment: What if the image has a different path than `images`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is.

Well you can try `parent()` function before addClass().

So all you have to do, just:

`$('.tiny-content a img').parent().addClass('lb-anchor');`

It would be pointing back to anchor instead of img